# Print screen button not taking screen shot

Tags: raspbian, pixel, screenshot

Raspbian, with kernel 4.4.38, and pixel desktop fails to take screen shot when I press the Print screen button. I don't know what the normal key-binding for the print-screen button is. in other Desktop environments, I might call a screenshot applet (like gnome-screenshot, or mate-screenshot) when pressing the screen-shot button, but i do not know what the name of that application would be in pixel.

Does pixel have a default screen-shot application?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the default Screenshot application is `scrot`, but it is a terminal application. Pixel runs scrot in the background which listens for the PrntScreen key.

Try opening a terminal and running `scrot`. Then check in the directory you're in for an image file...your screenshot.

Comment: I don't evidently have scrot installed, but I will try installing it.